# SQL error 26 visual studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Hello I've been getting this error message for some time now.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I'm developing an application in MVC4 with a local SQL Server Database in Visual Studio.

The error appears some times and some times not. The project is under version control and when I clone it down on another computer it mostly seems to work. I *am* able to access the database throught the Server Explorer tab - so I'm figuring it can't be a server issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions to what can be the cause of this. I'm at wits end and have tried all sorts of things like deleting the database and have my application recreate the database.

These are my connection strings:

```
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=default-FleaPortal-20131021113901;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\default-FleaPortal-20131021113901.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      <add name="UserConnection"    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=user-FleaPortal-20131108090400;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\user-FleaPortal-20131108090400.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since your server appears to be local, that should rule out any network problems.

That leaves problems with your service, so my guess would be that:

1. Your SQL Server service is configured to start up on-demand, and
2. It's not always starting up fast enough for the connection timeout

This would mean that the first time you try to connect after a system reboot or a SQL Server restart it would *sometimes* throw that error.

If this is the problem, then recommended solutions would be to either change the service startup from "Automatic (Delayed Start)" to "Automatic", or to extend the length of your connection timeout.

Comment: The only service, as far as I can see, that has anything to do with SQL is the service 'SQLWriter'. But that one is already set to automatic. But the yesterday I had the problem all day and it didn't seem to go away. This really beats me. Thank you for your input though.

Comment: @fredefox Check for a service named something like either "MSSQLSERVER" or "SQLEXPRESS".

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem involved having multiple Context-classes.

I had one class implementing DropCreateDatabaseAlways that seeded some data and another class that used Code First Migrations. These databases conflicted in some weird way.

I'm not fully aware what the actual problem was, but putting it all in one context class and moving my seed data to the Code First Migrations solved it.

So there you have it, if you did like me and run into this problem. Do it this way instead.

This really caused me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your application does not have enough rights to access the database.